# Quicksight - how to show aggregated value as Fraction

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I am creating a pivot table in quicksight, one of the rows I want to calculate the average so I have applied avaerage option on it. It aggregates it up to the root level 500/6 = 83.333 so far so good.
Now I want to tweak this a bit and instead of showing 83.333, I want to show it as fraction value like 5/6, it basically denotes 5 are passed out of 6. How I can achive the same ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know, QuickSight doesn't provide any such functionality out of the box. What you can do instead is get a total count of all the objects in the table and another count of the items that have passed and then display them one after another.